# How to choose what to render using GetServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to render specific text after a certain time and specific text before that certain time. I have tried using if-else logic in the component, however, it ends up generating HTML for a text that I want to conceal. So, I was wondering how in getServerSideProps, I can choose what to render in the front end function.

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSideProps` is used for data fetching when the data displayed to the user changes frequently. `getServerSideProps` won't be a viable option for  this,

You should use `setTimeout` in your `useEffect` hook to change state after a specific time and using that state to decide what to render .

Something like this :

```
export default function App () {
    const [flag , setFlag] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => setFlag(true) , 5000)
    })
    return(
        flag ? 
        <h1>state changed</h1>
        :
        <h1>some heading</h1>
    )
}
```